# forming Bigrams of words in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, n-gram

I have been trying to convert a pandas dataframe containing already tokenized words into bigrams but I have been unsuccessful. I have tried multiple codes but I either keep getting error messages or weird answers. I only started using python about 2 weeks ago and I'm really struggling with this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

This is what I've tried so far.

```
from nltk.util import ngrams

generic_tweets['bigrams'] = generic_tweets['tweet'].apply(lambda row: list(map(lambda x:ngrams(x,2), row)))   
generic_tweets['bigrams'].head()
```

where

```
generic_tweets['tweet'].head() 

0         [awww, thats, bummer, shoulda, got, david, car...
1         [upset, that, he, cant, update, his, facebook,...
2         [dived, many, time, ball, managed, save, rest,...
3            [whole, body, feel, itchy, like, it, on, fire]
4         [no, it, not, behaving, at, all, im, mad, why,...
5                                        [not, whole, crew]
6                                               [need, hug]
```

what I want is

```
0         [(awww, thats), (thats, bummer), (bummer, shoulda)...
1         [(upset, that), (that, he), (he, cant), (cant, update)...
2         [(dived, many), (many, time), (time, ball), (ball, managed)...
```

but what I am getting is

```
0    [<generator object ngrams at 0x000002A38014B84...
1    [<generator object ngrams at 0x000002A30BA0AB1...
2    [<generator object ngrams at 0x000002A3A9182B8...
3    [<generator object ngrams at 0x000002A3A918713...
4    [<generator object ngrams at 0x000002A3A91874F...
Name: bigrams, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for this output is hidden in the body of the lambda function you are applying:

```
generic_tweets['bigrams'] = generic_tweets['tweet'].apply(lambda row: list(map(lambda x:ngrams(x,2), row)))
```

I believe what you should do is instead of applying `ngrams(x,2)` do `list(ngrams(row,2))` which would get rid of the generators you are getting in the answer and give you the ngrams on the level of words instead of letters:

```
generi_tweets['bigrams'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda row: list(nltk.ngrams(row, 2)))
```

Another thing is, that accessing the values from the dataframe without encompassing `list` would disclose the results of `ngrams` function too.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now, however what I'm getting is 

0         [[(a, w), (w, w), (w, w)], [(t, h), (h, a), (a...
1         [[(u, p), (p, s), (s, e), (e, t)], [(t, h), (h...
2         [[(d, i), (i, v), (v, e), (e, d)], [(m, a), (a...
3         [[(w, h), (h, o), (o, l), (l, e)], [(b, o), (o...

Comment: i want the bigrams to be applied to the words instead of each alphabet

Comment: thanks for your response.
I'm hoping to get bigrams of words for each row instead of bigrams of alphabets

Comment: Refined the answer to give just that.

Comment: Hi
I used the refined code but I'm getting empty tuples

` [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [...
1    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [...
2    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [...
3    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [...
4    [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [..
`
any idea why that is?

Comment: If this time it helped you I would be grateful for indicating this by accepting the answer.

Comment: Hi, apologies. My jupyter notebook crashed yesterday (from having to run 400,000 rows of data) so I spent all this time trying to recover my code. I just tried it however and it works perfectly. Thanks once again. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your pandas series don't have in array form use below for getting bigrams

```
generic_tweets['bigrams'] = generic_tweets['tweet'].apply(lambda row: list(nltk.bigrams(row.split(' '))))
```

This is similar to

```
list(nltk.bigrams(['abc', 'def', 'ghi']))
```

Output will be

```
[['abc', 'def'], ['def', 'ghi']]
```